# Facebook Load Thumbnail

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, thumbnails, feed

I'm looking to try and mimmic facebook's thumbnail function.
Let me be more specific:
When you paste a link into your Facebook feed it will load thumbnail images from that link before you post it.
Does anybody out there know how to do this?
Thanks guys
Alex

Answer (score 1):

Facebook „scrapes” the given URL, and looks for [Open Graph](http://ogp.me/) meta elements, or in case it doesn’t find any, it tries to figure out relevant images & content from the HTML code itself.